# what is the purpose of http://username:password@host/

Tags: html, javascript

I tried to login to gmail using this but it didnt't work.I just saw this before opening gmail
[image: Boxes]

Is there something to automate such a thing

**EDIT:**

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine) also but din't work

**EDIT:**

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) website shows good instructions to proceed but after running as told its not opening my browser otherwise its fine according to the instructions mentioned.

Comment: This works for ftp auth, but there is ftp:// and not http://. Or maybe this is for websites there is some simple form of http auth. Gmail not the one who does that.

Comment: Why would you send your password in clear text?

Comment: ngen, it hashes the password, actually. However, it's still vulnerable to replay attacks.

Comment: I want to have somthing like this to login to websites without typing the password OR wothout using the feature of the browser "save password"

Comment: Then you'll need to build something custom on a per-website basis, this will usually involve constructing a form, and you'll be out of luck if they have protection against CSRF.

Answer (score 5):

In an http url, it's for HTTP authentication. HTTP authentication is rarely used. It's rarely used because web applications usually contain their own users list in a database instead of having the http server manage authentication.

The comments about its insecurity are somewhat misleading, because when done over SSL, it's exactly as secure as POST based logins. An MD5 hashed password challenge is also possible which you can read about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is another way to specify basic authentication credentials using the URL.  It isn't secure so most sites don't use it and I don't recommend it.  I believe the browser converts it to the header, but anyone sniffing your communication could use your account by simply sending the same header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Almost correct.  It's as insecure as the pop-up dialogue, the browser sends them both in exactly the same way.  It exists so that scripts and command-line tools can access sites that require authentication.  It's part of the official URL spec: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Comment: I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine) also but din't work

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something to automate such a thing

Depending on what you're trying to do, using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) might do the job (Selenium IDE has a Firefox plugin that allows you to record and playback actions on a website). If you only don't like to type passwords, Firefox has password saving built-in. If you want to automate it from a script, then you might need to reverse engineer gmails' authentication form and do HTTP Request yourself; alternatively you can try [python's mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [perl's mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/), which allows python/perl scripts to browse websites, fill forms, etc.